# How to create event tracking tool same as its google

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

How to create the event tracking tool for clients like google.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'PDF', '/salesForms/orderForm1.pdf']);
```

Comment: what events are u trying to track? just downloads? also are you looking for a full fledged app like google's?

Comment: i want to track all events and custome events app same as google

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't accept answers, I will still give you a pointer.

Add listeners for all the events that you want to track in the `body` tag. Since there is event bubbling, all the events triggered anywhere in the page (if `event.stopPropogation()` is not used), will be picked up. Then it is upto you to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanx..I have a central reporting app and I want to track events coming from multiple sites.